# Is there a document about how gremlin 'match()' works?

Tags: gremlin

I'm writing gremlin query with 'match()' traversal.  It seems some pattern matching behaves differently than other pattern languages.

1. How input traverser values are bound by pattern variables.

```
g.V('A', 'B').match(__.as('x'), __.as('y')).project('x', 'y')
==>[x:v[A],y:v[A]]
==>[x:v[B],y:v[B]]
```

I think pattern variable `x` and `y` have no constraints and result will be

```
==>[x:v[A],y:v[A]]
==>[x:v[A],y:v[B]]
==>[x:v[B],y:v[A]]
==>[x:v[B],y:v[B]]
```

It seems a constraint `x = y` is added implicitly.

2. When pattern variables are bound to values not listed in input traverser.

Sometimes, pattern variable are bound to values not listed in input:

```
g.V('A', 'B').match(__.as('x').out().as('y'), __.as('y'))
==>[x:v[A],y:v[B]]
==>[x:v[B],y:v[C]]
==>[x:v[B],y:v[D]]
```

In this query, we have more constraints than previous query.
So, less results are expected, but results increase by capturing vertices not in input traversers.

Is there a clear documentation when pattern variables can capture such vertices.

3. "The provided match pattern is unsolvable"

Similar query:

```
g.V('A', 'B').match(__.as('x').out().as('y'), __.as('z'))
The provided match pattern is unsolvable: [[MatchStartStep(z), MatchEndStep], [MatchStartStep(x), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), MatchEndStep(y)]]
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]y
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The provided match pattern is unsolvable: [[MatchStartStep(z), MatchEndStep], [MatchStartStep(x), VertexStep(OUT,vertex), MatchEndStep(y)]]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.MatchStep$MatchAlgorithm.lambda$static$0(MatchStep.java:690)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.MatchStep$CountMatchAlgorithm.apply(MatchStep.java:757)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.MatchStep$CountMatchAlgorithm.apply(MatchStep.java:723)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.step.map.MatchStep.standardAlgorithm(MatchStep.java:398)
```

This has less constraints than previous one.
What this error means.

Comment: The error message is actually pretty clear, the pattern is unsolvable. It's not clear where z is supposed to come from.

Comment: The first query has a same problem about y but is solvable, why?

Comment: Not really. There's no traversal within match(), hence x == y.

Comment: Ok.  This error seems nice.  x == y prevents this error implicitly and seems main cause of strange behavior.