# Match clause is unsolvable. Behavior is not clear

Tags: pattern-matching, graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm compiling queries programmatically at runtime and the match clause is the more general way I could think of to perform this task. Most of them are running fine but some, at some point, return the "Unsolvable pattern" exception.

I've checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609832/is-there-a-document-about-how-gremlin-match-works) as the only similar question on SO but it doesn't answer or explain the problem, at least to me.

Here's my failing attempt.

```
g.V().match(
        __.as('loc').has('guid','EGLD').out('instanceOfSupClass').hasLabel('Main_Location'),
        __.as('meter1').out('instanceOfSupClass').hasLabel('Electricity_Meter'),
        __.as('meter2').out('instanceOfSupClass').hasLabel('Electricity_Meter'),
        __.as('class').out('instanceOfSupClass').hasLabel('Cleaned_Electricty_Meter'),
        __.as('meter1').out('hasLocation').as('loc'),
        __.as('meter2').out('isPartOf').as('meter1'),
        __.as('meter2').out('hasTimeSeries').as('class')
    )
```

with the dreaded:

```java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The provided match pattern is unsolvable: [[MatchStartStep(_m), VertexStep(OUT,[is],vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(A)]), MatchEndStep], [MatchStartStep(_m2), VertexStep(OUT,[bar],edge), StoreStep(edges), EdgeVertexStep(IN), MatchEndStep(_m1)], [MatchStartStep(_m1), VertexStep(OUT,[foo],edge), StoreStep(edges), EdgeVertexStep(IN), MatchEndStep(_l)], [MatchStartStep(c), VertexStep(OUT,[is],vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(D)]), MatchEndStep], [MatchStartStep(_m1), VertexStep(OUT,[is],vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(B)]), MatchEndStep], [MatchStartStep(_l), VertexStep(OUT,[is],vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(A)]), MatchEndStep], [MatchStartStep(_m1), VertexStep(OUT,[beer],edge), StoreStep(edges), EdgeVertexStep(IN), MatchEndStep(c)]]
```

Now here's a similar one that works instead:

```
g.V().match(
        __.as('loc').has('guid','EGLD').out('instanceOfSupClass').hasLabel('Main_Location'),
        __.as('meter1').out('instanceOfSupClass').hasLabel('Electricity_Meter'),
        __.as('meter2').out('instanceOfSupClass').hasLabel('Electricity_Meter'),
        __.as('class').out('instanceOfSupClass').hasLabel('Cleaned_Electricty_Meter'),
        __.as('meter1').out('hasLocation').as('loc'),
        __.as('meter2').out('isPartOf').as('meter1'),
        __.as('meter1').out('hasTimeSeries').as('class')
    )
```

I'd expect both of them to return one result (athough different ones since they are different patterns).

I'd like to understand why it is failing and eventually if it is a bug or if I'm missing something.

EDIT:
add examples and parallelisms between the toy graph (which doesn't give the error) and my real case queries (I can't upload the example of my graph)

```
beer_graph=TinkerGraph.open()
g = beer_graph.traversal()

A = g.addV('A').next()
B = g.addV('B').next()
C = g.addV('C').next()

LOK = g.addV().next()
MOK1 = g.addV().next()
MOK2 = g.addV().next()
COK = g.addV().next()

g.V(LOK).addE('is').to(A)
g.V(MOK1).addE('is').to(B)
g.V(MOK2).addE('is').to(B)
g.V(COK).addE('is').to(C)

g.V(MOK1).addE('foo').to(LOK)
g.V(MOK2).addE('bar').to(MOK1)
g.V(MOK2).addE('beer').to(COK)

LKO = g.addV().property('guid', 'LKO').next()
MKO1 = g.addV().next()
MKO2 = g.addV().next()
CKO = g.addV().next()

g.V(LKO).addE('is').to(A)
g.V(MKO1).addE('is').to(B)
g.V(MKO2).addE('is').to(B)
g.V(CKO).addE('is').to(C)

g.V(MKO1).addE('foo').to(LKO)
g.V(MKO2).addE('bar').to(MKO1)
g.V(MKO1).addE('beer').to(CKO)


g.V().match(
        __.as('_l').has('guid', 'LKO').outE('is').inV().hasLabel('A'),
        __.as('_m1').outE('is').inV().hasLabel('B'),
        __.as('_m2').outE('is').inV().hasLabel('B'),
        __.as('_c').outE('is').inV().hasLabel('C'),
        __.as('_m1').outE('foo').inV().as('_l'),
        __.as('_m2').outE('bar').inV().as('_m1'),
        __.as('_m1').outE('beer').inV().as('_c')
    )

g.V().match(
        __.as('_l').outE('is').inV().hasLabel('A'),
        __.as('_m1').outE('is').inV().hasLabel('B'),
        __.as('_m2').outE('is').inV().hasLabel('B'),
        __.as('_c').outE('is').inV().hasLabel('C'),
        __.as('_m1').outE('foo').inV().as('_l'),
        __.as('_m2').outE('bar').inV().as('_m1'),
        __.as('_m2').outE('beer').inV().as('_c')
    )
```

Both work and return correctly a result. Now, moving away from the toy graph, these are the traversal that get constructed at runtime by my project:

```
g.V().match(
        __.as('loc').has('guid','EGLD').out('instanceOfSupClass').hasLabel('Main_Location'),
        __.as('meter1').out('instanceOfSupClass').hasLabel('Electricity_Meter'),
        __.as('meter2').out('instanceOfSupClass').hasLabel('Electricity_Meter'),
        __.as('class').out('instanceOfSupClass').hasLabel('Cleaned_Electricty_Meter'),
        __.as('meter1').out('hasLocation').as('loc'),
        __.as('meter2').out('isPartOf').as('meter1'),
        __.as('meter2').out('hasTimeSeries').as('class')
    )


[
[MatchStartStep(loc), HasStep([guid.eq(EGLD)]), VertexStep(OUT,[instanceOfSupClass],vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(Main_Location)]), MatchEndStep], 
[MatchStartStep(meter1), VertexStep(OUT,[instanceOfSupClass],vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(Electricity_Meter)]), MatchEndStep], 
[MatchStartStep(meter2), VertexStep(OUT,[instanceOfSupClass],vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(Electricity_Meter)]), MatchEndStep], 
[MatchStartStep(class), VertexStep(OUT,[instanceOfSupClass],vertex), HasStep([~label.eq(Cleaned_Electricty_Meter)]), MatchEndStep], 
[MatchStartStep(meter1), VertexStep(OUT,[hasLocation],vertex), MatchEndStep(loc)], 
[MatchStartStep(meter2), VertexStep(OUT,[isPartOf],vertex), MatchEndStep(meter1)], 
[MatchStartStep(meter2), VertexStep(OUT,[hasTimeSeries],vertex), MatchEndStep(class)]
]
```

Compared to the compiled previous one

```
g.V().match(
        __.as('_l').has('guid', 'LKO').outE('is').inV().hasLabel('A'),
        __.as('_m1').outE('is').inV().hasLabel('B'),
        __.as('_m2').outE('is').inV().hasLabel('B'),
        __.as('_c').outE('is').inV().hasLabel('C'),
        __.as('_m1').outE('foo').inV().as('_l'),
        __.as('_m2').outE('bar').inV().as('_m1'),
        __.as('_m1').outE('beer').inV().as('_c')
    )

[
[MatchStartStep(_l), HasStep([guid.eq(LKO)]),    VertexStep(OUT,[is],vertex),                   HasStep([~label.eq(A)]), MatchEndStep],
[MatchStartStep(_m1),                VertexStep(OUT,[is],vertex),                   HasStep([~label.eq(B)]), MatchEndStep], 
[MatchStartStep(_m2),                VertexStep(OUT,[is],vertex),                   HasStep([~label.eq(B)]), MatchEndStep], 
[MatchStartStep(_c),                 VertexStep(OUT,[is],vertex),                   HasStep([~label.eq(C)]), MatchEndStep], 
[MatchStartStep(_m1),                VertexStep(OUT,[foo],vertex), MatchEndStep(_l)], 
[MatchStartStep(_m2),                VertexStep(OUT,[bar],vertex), MatchEndStep(_m1)], 
[MatchStartStep(_m1),                VertexStep(OUT,[beer],vertex), MatchEndStep(_c)]
]
```

Why the "unsolvable pattern" exception, and why changing the graph would matter? If the pattern is "unsolvable" on the current graph I expect an empty result, not an Exception...

EDIT 2: found the difference, not understanding the problem

I managed to reconstruct the "incriminated" script, this one DOESN'T work...

```
g.V().match(
        __.as("_loc").has("guid","EGLD").out("instanceOfSupClass").hasLabel("Main_Location"),
        __.as("_meter1").out("instanceOfSupClass").hasLabel("Electricity_Meter"),
        __.as("_meter1").outE("hasLocation").store("edges").inV().as("_loc"),
        __.as("_meter1").outE("hasTimeSeries").store("edges").inV().as("class"),
        __.as("_meter2").out("instanceOfSupClass").hasLabel("Electricity_Meter"),
        __.as("_meter2").outE("isPartOf").store("edges").inV().as("_meter1"),
        __.as("class").out("instanceOfSupClass").hasLabel("Virtual_Anomaly_Class_Time_Series")
    )
```

This one works...

```
g.V().match(
        __.as("_meter2").out("instanceOfSupClass").hasLabel("Electricity_Meter"),
        __.as("_meter2").outE("isPartOf").store("edges").inV().as("_meter1"),
        __.as("_meter1").outE("hasLocation").store("edges").inV().as("_loc"),
        __.as("_meter1").out("instanceOfSupClass").hasLabel("Electricity_Meter"),
        __.as("class").out("instanceOfSupClass").hasLabel("Virtual_Anomaly_Class_Time_Series"),
        __.as("_loc").has("guid","EGLD").out("instanceOfSupClass").hasLabel("Main_Location"),
        __.as("_meter1").outE("hasTimeSeries").store("edges").inV().as("class")
    )
```

**SO ORDER MATTERS**

Comment: To me, both patterns appear to be unsolvable as it's not clear where `_c` is coming from. Please provide a sample graph and show that one of the queries works / returns the expected result.

Comment: @DanielKuppitz Ehy, I tried to elaborate more about the problem and used examples and parallelism between the provided toy graph and my real application. I don't get why Queries that compiles to the same structure would behave differently on two different graphs.

Comment: All the match patterns in your updated post are valid. I tried them all, none of them throws an exception.

Comment: @DanielKuppitz I managed to recreate the incriminated script by reconverting back the failing bytecode to a script... this effectively fail on both the app and the console... So apparently order matters???

Comment: I take back what I said earlier. The "unsolvable pattern" error is, in fact, a runtime error (i thought it's a compile-time error). So the only time when you'll see it is actually when you start to iterate through real data. I studied the `MatchStep` code for a while now and I don't think that `match()` was ever supposed to reorder traversals to make the pattern solvable. The first label is considered the start label and from there on the path to every other label should be clear (assume that match traversals are processed sequentially).

Comment: Well, there's some kind of sorting, otherwise, your full example wouldn't work. But apparently, that's not something to rely on.

Comment: @DanielKuppitz Even though I suggest a clarification in the documentations of Tinkerpop itself, if you want to turn your comment in an answer I feel like it actually clarify the situation and should be accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit, that I don't fully understand the `MatchStep` code. There is some kind of sorting in it, but obviously, you can't rely on this sorting to turn your pattern into a solvable pattern.

When you build the patterns, you should make sure, that the first label matches the incoming element and all further start-labels are in reach following the start-label and its connected end-labels. Does this make sense? As an example on the modern graph:

```
gremlin> g.V().match(
......1>     __.as('a').out('knows').as('b'),
......2>     __.as('b').out('created').as('c'))
==>[a:v[1],b:v[4],c:v[5]]
==>[a:v[1],b:v[4],c:v[3]]
gremlin> g.V().match(
......1>     __.as('b').out('created').as('c'),
......2>     __.as('a').out('knows').as('b'))
The provided match pattern is unsolvable: [[MatchStartStep(a), VertexStep(OUT,[knows],vertex), MatchEndStep(b)], [MatchStartStep(b), VertexStep(OUT,[created],vertex), MatchEndStep(c)]]
```

The first pattern is easily solvable. From `a` you can go to `b` and once you know what `b` is, you can go to `c`. Now, the second traversal just swapped the patterns, but it's easy to see why it's unsolvable; you start from `b`, from there you can go to `c`, but then it's not clear where `a` is coming from. Note, that `a.out.b` can not simply be converted into `b.in.a` as some graph databases have unidirected edges. However, if you know that edges can be traversed in both directions and you turn it around manually, then the traversal will just work:

```
gremlin> g.V().match(
......1>     __.as('b').out('created').as('c'),
......2>     __.as('b').in('knows').as('a'))
==>[a:v[1],b:v[4],c:v[5]]
==>[a:v[1],b:v[4],c:v[3]]
```

In your code sample, the start-label should actually be `_m2` in order to make all other labels resolvable. Why does it work, even though you didn't specify it as the first start-label? I don't know, for some reason, the internal sorting algorithm comes up with the correct order of patterns, but as I've mentioned initially, this shouldn't be expected.

Comment: I just noticed that the error message of my failing traversal actually contains a solvable form of patterns. It's really confusing; if you want, create a Jira ticket for that issue, perhaps someone dares to analyze that crazy code.

Comment: Regarding the reordering part I quote the documentation: "The default MatchAlgorithm provided is called CountMatchAlgorithm and it dynamically revises the pattern execution plan by sorting the patterns according to their filtering capabilities (i.e. largest set reduction patterns execute first)"